# Is there some way in JPA to auto-increment a column automatically based on other value

Tags: java, jpa

I have an entity called as an Employee

```
@Entity
public Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "target")
    private int target;
}
```

Now what I want to achieve is that whenever I persist an employee with same name instead of a new record being created I would like the target to increment.

For e.g. if I persist an employee twice as follows:

```
Employee e1 = new Employee();
e1.setName("John");
em.persit();
```

the target should be 1 now

then if I do this:

```
Employee e2 = new Employee();
e1.setName("John");
em.persit();
```

target automatically increments itself and now its value should be 2. Because Employee by the name John already was in the table.

Comment: I would always use the service layer for this problem (`EmployeeService.addEmployee()`), and check for an existing entity there. You are trying to break the API of JPA, as `EntityManager.persist()` should always create a new entity. It will lead to spurious errors and make it difficult to understand for others what is really happening.

Answer (score 1):

If your database support triggers, it should be the way to go ! mysql for example https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html.

Other than that, I don't see how it can be done automatically, you need to query for the employees having the same name, then set the correct target for the new employee.

Comment: Trigger sounds like a good idea, but how can I write something like that in my case. The link and few other forums I went through have no examples like that.